# How to attach reference of an object to a ListView item?

Tags: c#, winforms, listview

I'm currently building a Windows Form application to list all clients from a SQL Database. After Querying all my clients, I'm displaying them in a ListView, allowing user to click on one of the client to get further informations. How can I attach a reference to my "Client" object to the item in the listview, in order to recover this specific object when clicking ?

I've tried to use indexes of the listView, the only problem is that I have a filtering function (Search) that messes with the order of the clients when used.

```
public class Client
    {
        public string _name;
        public int _id;

        public Client(string name, int id)
        {
            _name = name;
            _id = id;
        }
    }

public Form1()
    {
        public Client[10] clients;
        for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
        {
            Client[i] = new Client(i.ToString(), i);
        }

        InitializeComponent();

        foreach (Client client in clients)
        {
            ListViewItem item = new ListViewItem(client._name);
            item.Tag = client;
            ClientListView.Items.Add(item);
        }
    }

private void ClientListView_SelectedIndexChanged(object s, EventArgs e)
    {
            if (clientListView.SelectedItems.Count == 1)
            {
                var item = clientListView.SelectedItems[0];
                Client client = (Client)item.Tag;
            }
    }
```

This solution only creates a new Client object when an item is selected, is there no way to point to the original object contained in the clients array ? Passing by reference maybe, but it doesn't seems to work, maybe the tag is not a good solution...

Comment: `ListViewItem` has a `Tag` property which is object.

Comment: The code and your text do not match. Either you did not understand what your code does, or you copied the wrong code?

Comment: What do you think `Client client = (Client)item.Tag;` is doing, and why is it not what you want ("point to the original object contained in the clients array")?

Comment: If you are working with data from a database, a `DataGrtidView` and a few lines to implement Data Binding would be much, much simpler than a ListView - and everything would not be converted to text.

Comment: Thanks @nvoigt, I thought using Client client = (Client)item.Tag; would create a new object, but it seems not.

Comment: @ŇɏssaPøngjǣrdenlarp I'm actually using MaterialSkin Library, and it doesn't contains the DataGridView, I could try to style it the proper way but I'm not good enough with WinForms Properties.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Every winforms control (System.Windows.Forms.Control) has a Tag variable which is an object (System.Object). That means you can put any reference to the Tag.
For example:

```
Client client = new Client();
btn = new Button();
btn.Tag = client;
```

Then, in another method you can use the Tag.

```
Client oldClient = btn.Tag as Client;
```

Of course you can use `(Client)btn.Tag` but for me `btn.Tag as Client` is much easier to use, and to see on other people's code.

P.S: It will not create a new Client with the same data of the Client at the start of the code. It is saving the reference (the location of the object in the application's memory), not the data.